# How to disable multiple plugins in pytest.ini?

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I have tests within the same repository (separate pytest.ini files) that require different pytest plugins. How can I disable multiple plugins in pytest.ini without uninstalling them?

https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/plugins.html#findpluginname

```
addopts = --nomigrations --reuse-db -s -p no:pytest-splinter
```

works fine, but I also want to disable pytest-django and pytest-bdd for one of the test suites. How can I do that? I've tried:

```
addopts = --nomigrations --reuse-db -s -p no:pytest-splinter -p no:pytest-django 

addopts = --nomigrations --reuse-db -s -p no:pytest-splinter no:pytest-django 

addopts = --nomigrations --reuse-db -s -p no:pytest-splinter pytest-django
```

all fail, and the documentation doesn't describe how this is done. Any pointers greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The usage with the repeated passing of the `-p` option is the correct one. However, you are using the wrong plugin names. Instead of passing the PyPI package names, use the `pytest` plugin names:

```
addopts = --nomigrations --reuse-db -s -p no:pytest-splinter -p no:django
```

When in doubt whether using correct plugin name, use `pytest --trace-config` to list all installed plugins along with their names:

```
$ pytest --trace-config
...
PLUGIN registered: <module 'pytest_html.plugin' from '/Users/hoefling/.virtualenvs/stackoverflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytest_html/plugin.py'>
PLUGIN registered: <module 'pytest_django.plugin' from '/Users/hoefling/.virtualenvs/stackoverflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytest_django/plugin.py'>
...
=============================================== test session starts ===============================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.4, pytest-3.7.3.dev26+g7f6c2888, py-1.5.4, pluggy-0.7.1
using: pytest-3.7.3.dev26+g7f6c2888 pylib-1.5.4
setuptools registered plugins:
  pytest-metadata-1.7.0 at /Users/hoefling/.virtualenvs/stackoverflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytest_metadata/plugin.py
  pytest-html-1.19.0 at /Users/hoefling/.virtualenvs/stackoverflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytest_html/plugin.py
  pytest-django-3.4.2 at /Users/hoefling/.virtualenvs/stackoverflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytest_django/plugin.py
active plugins:
    metadata : /Users/hoefling/.virtualenvs/stackoverflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytest_metadata/plugin.py
    html     : /Users/hoefling/.virtualenvs/stackoverflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytest_html/plugin.py
    django   : /Users/hoefling/.virtualenvs/stackoverflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytest_django/plugin.py
...
```

#### When `pytest --trace-config` fails

In that case, you could query the metadata of the installed packages directly, for example using `pkg_resources` (part of `setuptools` package, which is preinstalled on most of the Python distributions nowadays; if not, install as usual: `pip install --user setuptools`):

```
import os
import pkg_resources

data = ['{}-{}: {}'.format(dist.project_name, dist.version,
                           ' '.join(dist.get_entry_map(group='pytest11').keys()))
        for dist in pkg_resources.working_set if dist.get_entry_map(group='pytest11')]

print(os.linesep.join(data))
```

Example output:

```
requests-mock-1.5.2: requests_mock
pytest-splinter-1.9.1: pytest-splinter
pytest-metadata-1.7.0: metadata
pytest-html-1.19.0: html
pytest-django-3.4.2: django
```

Another possibility to find out the plugin name is to look in the plugin's source code. The name is in the plugin's entry point declaration:

```
entry_points={'pytest11': [
    'plugin_name=plugin.registration.module',
]}
```

Thus,

- [the plugin name for `pytest-splinter` is `pytest-splinter`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-splinter/blob/0ee5590c469b27221e7a93980cc163a195a42014/setup.py#L52) (duh!),
- [the plugin name for `pytest-django` is `django`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django/blob/ed77ef2916013eaa7924ef6d21f7c8266ae4f670/setup.cfg#L45).

Comment: Ah ha! Thanks @hoefling, I couldn't get --trace-config to load because the plugins themselves were throwing exceptions (hence the need to disable them).

Comment: Oh, I see! This is a much more interesting question - what to do when `pytest --trace-config` fails in the first place because some plugin raises an error early. You could then do a direct query of the installed packages metadata; I've updated the answer with a simple helper script that does that.

Comment: That's really useful! Thanks for the extra info @hoefling!!