# Start pytest with all plugins disabled

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I've been debugging a weird pytest startup issue and wanted to check if any of the plugins is causing a problem.

Is it possible to start pytest and ask it to not load any of the plugins?

From what I see in the documentation, there is a way to only turn off a [specific plugin by name](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html?highlight=disable%20plugins#disabling-plugins).

Comment: here is your [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52049297/how-to-disable-multiple-plugins-in-pytest-ini) i suppose

Comment: @prashantrana ah, it's almost what I need, but I can adapt/improve it to disable all the plugins. Will post what I've got soon if nobody answers. Thanks for the link!

Comment: If you mean disabling all the third party plugins, you can use smth like `python -c "import pkg_resources; print(' '.join('-p no:' + ' '.join(dist.get_entry_map(group='pytest11').keys()) for dist in pkg_resources.working_set if dist.get_entry_map(group='pytest11')))" | xargs pytest` (sure, it's clumsy but should do the trick).

Comment: @hoefling post your answer in answer section.. it will be helpful in future

Comment: @hoefling alright, I took the liberty to put it into the answer breaking the magic down into individual "spells" :)

Comment: @alecxe no worries, I guess I simply forgot about that. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting a solution [recommended in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53836553/start-pytest-with-all-plugins-disabled#comment94533286_53836553):

```
python -c "import pkg_resources; print(' '.join('-p no:' + ' '.join(dist.get_entry_map(group='pytest11').keys()) for dist in pkg_resources.working_set if dist.get_entry_map(group='pytest11')))" | xargs pytest
```

This looks a bit magical, but, if analyzed and broken down, it starts to make more sense:

- [`pkg_resources`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html) is a part of `setuptools` which allows to access package resource files, configs and setup configurations
- `.get_entry_map()` returns the dictionary of "entry point" objects
- we are filtering out `pytest11` entry points as this is what [Pytest itself is using to discover plugins](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/writing_plugins.html)
- then, we are feeding the filtered out entry points into the [`-p no:` command line argument](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/plugins.html#deactivating-unregistering-a-plugin-by-name) which is a Pytest's way to disable a plugin

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52055720/771848).